# Accessing EJB through service class

Tags: java, ejb, persistence

I need to access an EJB to add/delete objects on a database, currently my annotated controller (using spring) calls the service class that in turn calls the facade to do solve my database requests.
I am getting this exception:

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.CadmusWeb.service.ClienteService.novoCliente(ClienteService.java:21)
    at br.com.CadmusWeb.controller.LoginController.clienteNovo(LoginController.java:100)
(Marked with >> the lines the exception póints out)

I am new to the usage of EJB

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

  private ClientService cliServ;

  public LoginController() {
    this.cliServ = new ClientService();
  }

@RequestMapping("clientMenu/clientNew.html")
public ModelAndView clientNew(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Client cli = new Client();
    cli.setName((String) request.getAttribute("clientName"));

    >>cliServ.newClient(cli);

    return new ModelAndView("clientMenuNew");
}
```

The service class

```
public class ClientService {

@EJB
  private ClientFacade clientFacade;

  public void novoClient(Client cli){
  >>clientFacade.create(cli);
  }

  public void deleteClient(Client cli){
    clientFacade.remove(cli);
  }
}
```

ClientFacade

```
@Stateless
public class ClientFacade extends AbstractFacade<Client> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "WebProjectPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public ClientFacade() {
    super(Client.class);
}

}
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that request.getAttribute("clientName")); is not returning a null value?

Comment: If I set the client name to a hardcoded value there is no change, the same exception is raised.

Comment: Is `ClientService` container managed, if not try JNDI lookup.

Comment: I'm gonna check that but, how would I know if it is or not container managed?

Comment: The glassfish server has this output:
INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB ClientFacade: [java:global/CadmusWeb/ClientFacade!session.ClientFacade, java:global/CadmusWeb/ClientFacade]

If I add this line to the service constructor (with the try/catch block):  
this.clientFacade = (ClientFacade) initialContext.lookup("java:global/CadmusWeb/ClienteFacade"); I get a javax.ejb.EJBException at the same lines as the exception on the question and one at the AbstractFacade Create() method.

Comment: I also tried to declare an entity manager with the @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ProjectPU") and use it instead of the clientFacade but I still hit the nullpointerexception.

Comment: From reading other sources I suppose the problem is that dependency injection is not working, I tried using local interface and using it instead of the implementation but I STILL reach a null pointer exception

Comment: @user1934495 Ensure that you are using appropriate JNDI name as it varies with server for lookup.